# Flutter - Snapshot from Sub-collection

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I was reading several answers here but I could not get better understanding to solve my issue which is the following...
I don't know how to get the **"docId"** in the code below...
I want to query a sub-collection "**People**" as snapshot for the stream method which I will listen using Bloc...
I am not able to understand how to get the docId. Anyone could help me with this?

[image]

Thanks

```
Stream<People> statusMember({required String email}) {
    var user = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final snap = _firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user!.email)
        .collection('people') //sub-collection
        .doc(docId) // docId as reference? How to get it?
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => People.fromSnapshot(snapshot)); // model

    print(snap);
    return snap;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By digging more into the Firebase documentation, it is not possible to read docs in a sub-collection the way I wanted. Therefore, I've changed my approach and the code looks like this:

```
Stream<People?> statusMember({required String email}) {
    var user = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final snap = _firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user!.email)
        .collection('people')
        .where('email', isEqualTo: email)
        .snapshots()
        .map(
      (snappshot) {
        for (var doc in snappshot.docs) {
          return People.fromSnapshot(doc);
        }
      },
    );

    print(snap);
    return snap;
  }
```

it is working as expected.